# deleting repeated elements from matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have some problems while working with matlab. I am trying to make a new matrix 2x5000 (time and location) and I need to delete cells in which I have the same value of time as was somewhere before.

And the second thing: I have two vectors and I need to create a new one in which I have first element from the first vector, and second from the second vector one and so on (third from first, forth from second).

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

First question: Use the second output argument of `unique`, it returns the indices of the non repeated elements.

Second question:

```
%example data
A=[1,2,3,4]
B=[5,6,7,8]
%connect to a matrix
C=([A;B])
%convert to a vector
C=C(:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
close all; clear all;

v1 = [1 2 3 4 5; 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5];
v2 = [1 2 3 4 5; 0.15 0.25 0.35 0.45 0.55];

% merge
v12 = zeros(size(v1, 1), size(v1, 2) + size(v2, 2));
v12(:, 1:2:end) = v1;
v12(:, 2:2:end) = v2;
v12

% unique
i = 1;
while i < size(v12, 2)
  items = find(v12(1, i) == v12(1,:));
  if length(items) > 1
    items = items(2:end);
    v12(:, items) = [];
  end
  i = i + 1;
end
v12
```

Output:

```
v12 =

   1.00000   1.00000   2.00000   2.00000   3.00000   3.00000   4.00000   4.00000   5.00000   5.00000
   0.10000   0.15000   0.20000   0.25000   0.30000   0.35000   0.40000   0.45000   0.50000   0.55000

v12 =

   1.00000   2.00000   3.00000   4.00000   5.00000
   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000   0.50000
```

Comment: ` i++` is not valid Matlab syntax.

Comment: Thank you. I've added "i=i+1" instead of "i++" and "else" before it and it works.

Comment: I use Octave instead of Matlab. `i` increment should be outside of `if` statement - my mistake.